# Need to return a Single JSON response for two serializers in a customized way

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**serializers**

```
class Consolidated_Final(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model= Users
        fields= ['users','id','employee_name','billable_and_non_billable']

    def get_users(self,obj):
        query = Add_Job.objects.all()
        return Add_Job_Serializers(query, many =True).data
```

**views**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def final_view(request):
    q1 = Users.objects.values('id','employee_name','billable_and_non_billable',)
    query = Consolidated_Final(q1,many=True)
    return Response(query.data)
```

It is returning me the JSON response as

```
[
    {
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "job_name": "timesheet",
                "Hours": "12:12:00",
                "start_Date": "0121-12-12T12:12:00+05:53",
                "end_Date": "1211-12-12T12:12:00+05:53",
                "client": 1,
                "project": 1,
                "user": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "job_name": "Add",
                "Hours": "12:12:00",
                "start_Date": "1212-12-12T12:01:00+05:53",
                "end_Date": "0121-12-12T12:12:00+05:53",
                "client": 1,
                "project": 2,
                "user": 2
            }
        ],
        "id": 1,
        "employee_name": "vinoth",
        "billable_and_non_billable": "Billable"
    },
    {
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "job_name": "timesheet",
                "Hours": "12:12:00",
                "start_Date": "0121-12-12T12:12:00+05:53",
                "end_Date": "1211-12-12T12:12:00+05:53",
                "client": 1,
                "project": 1,
                "user": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "job_name": "Add",
                "Hours": "12:12:00",
                "start_Date": "1212-12-12T12:01:00+05:53",
                "end_Date": "0121-12-12T12:12:00+05:53",
                "client": 1,
                "project": 2,
                "user": 2
            }
        ],
        "id": 2,
        "employee_name": "Maari",
        "billable_and_non_billable": "Billable"
    },
    {
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "job_name": "timesheet",
                "Hours": "12:12:00",
                "start_Date": "0121-12-12T12:12:00+05:53",
                "end_Date": "1211-12-12T12:12:00+05:53",
                "client": 1,
                "project": 1,
                "user": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "job_name": "Add",
                "Hours": "12:12:00",
                "start_Date": "1212-12-12T12:01:00+05:53",
                "end_Date": "0121-12-12T12:12:00+05:53",
                "client": 1,
                "project": 2,
                "user": 2
            }
        ],
        "id": 3,
        "employee_name": "Maari",
        "billable_and_non_billable": "Billable"
    }
]
```

I need the JSON response as

```
[
    {
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "job_name": "timesheet",
                "Hours": "12:12:00",
                "start_Date": "0121-12-12T12:12:00+05:53",
                "end_Date": "1211-12-12T12:12:00+05:53",
                "client": 1,
                "project": 1,
                "user": 1
            }
        ],
        "id": 1,
        "employee_name": "vinoth",
        "billable_and_non_billable": "Billable"
    },
    {
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "job_name": "Add",
                "Hours": "12:12:00",
                "start_Date": "1212-12-12T12:01:00+05:53",
                "end_Date": "0121-12-12T12:12:00+05:53",
                "client": 1,
                "project": 2,
                "user": 2
            }
        ],
        "id": 2,
        "employee_name": "Maari",
        "billable_and_non_billable": "Billable"
    },
    {
        "users": [
        ],
        "id": 3,
        "employee_name": "Maari",
        "billable_and_non_billable": "Billable"
    }
]
```

I need to get the single JSON response by combining for User id: 1 need to add the Job details user:1 as a single JSON response. But now it is displaying all the jobs under all the users. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: you can write a serializer for ```users``` and and use it in your employee serializer. ```users=UserSerializers()```

Comment: Also remember about adding many=True in UserSerializers()

Comment: I tried but still I didnt get the output I wanted. I need the output as i mentioned above on the Need JSON reponse one. I need only the values for User:1 in the Id:1 in the JSON response but it is returning me the both User:1 and User:2 for all Id's.